# Porting current number and forwarding to new phone number

Tags: twilio

So, a little context for you first: Our app only has forwarding and text messaging capabilities for our clients. Basically, we just set up a forwarding number in twilio for our client and they use that as their public number (on websites, advertisements, Google, etc.). Then when their customers call that number we ask them a quick question using the phone menu before forwarding the call onto their regular land line and sending them a text message later.

What do you suggest we do when someone wants to keep their current number (land line or otherwise) as the main phone number (online, website, ads, etc.) instead of using a new forwarding number?

Would they port their current number over to twilio, and then just get a new number with their main phone provider that we'd forward the ported number to?

I'm sure this is a common problem, so wondering what the best way approach it would be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

If they want to continue using their POTS equipment then what you described is  the only option.  If they were able to move over to a pure VoIP system then there are more options.

You could use Twilio Client to build web and/or mobile VoIP apps for them.  Or you could stand to a VoIP server (like Astrisk or FreeSWITCH) for them to connect VoIP phones to.

Of course they would still have to have an internet connection with for either of the VoIP options.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the insight. You're saying this is the only option?    Port their current number over to twilio, and then just get a new number with their main phone provider that we'd forward the ported number to.

Comment: If they want to keep using their POTS telephone equipment, yes.  I updated the answer to try to remove that ambiguity.  Moving to VoIP offers more options.

Comment: Great, that makes sense. Do you know if traditional phone companies will typically give a customer a new phone number and let them poet their current one?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with doing that so I can't really give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but it was at the top of my search for questions about porting for sms capabilities. Having worked 20 years in B2B telecom I can answer the last part of this in case anyone else needs to know.

If you go to any provider and request a number to be ported from the existing provider, the "losing carrier" cannot refuse to port the number ***as long as the number is active***. I stress this point because if they are past-due, they still have to port it. But if the service is temporarily or permanently disconnected they don't and usually won't port it. The port has to come from the company winning the business. Don't contact the existing carrier about it because they can't "push" the number out. Instead, the new carrier will have you fill out a Letter of Authorization (LOA) to port it that gets submitted with the port request. Its very important that all of the details on this form match the billing record or it will get declined. So normally you would provide a copy of the current bill with the LOA.